# Windows Phone : How to find people or phone using my app within a specified radius?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, location

I've created an app which is kind of a social network. And now if i hit "search friends" button in my app, i should be able to find other people who are using this app ( friends ) within a radius of say 5 miles. How do i go about to do that?

By the way, i'm using Windows Phone 7.1.1 sdk.

Comment: Collect device locations from your app. Publish to your app server. Query your app server for locations near you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As michael suggested, you will need to manage it server side.  Periodically, collect the coordinates (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher%28VS.92%29.aspx) and push them to a service (WCF, REST, or otherwise) that you expose on a server you control.  On the server, store the coordinates in some sort of database.  One that supports spatial queries would be easiest, but it is not required.  MSSQL allows definition of a column of type geography which can store a Latitude/longitude tuple.

Then, when one of your members queries the users located nearby, collect that user's current position, push it to the server, and run a query to find the other users with points within a current distance.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx for an example on SQL server.

The same set of information could be stored in MySQL or any other RDBMS, but depending upon their featureset, you may need to do the computation yourself.  It is a fun problem boiling down to the pythagorean theorem for short distances or some trig if you want to do a great circle distance.  See http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html for more.